# Trigger a click event on element and then unmount it

Tags: reactjs, event-loop

I'm trying to implement a suggestion list. I use `<input/>` followed by a number of `<div>`s. When the input element is focused, list, or divs, will show; when the input element is not focused, or blurred, the divs are unmounted. I want to print the content in div before the boolean variable `isFocused` is set to `false`. But now if I blur the input and click div, the `printContent` will not be triggered because `isFocused` has been set to false. Now I am using `setTimeout` to deal with this problem. Is there a better way to resolve this? Here is the code snippet: 
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/happy-butterfly-b4b8e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from 'react'; 

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = {
            isFocused: false
        }
    }

    handleFocus = () => {
        this.setState({ isFocused: true }); 
    }

    handleBlur = () => {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isFocused: false }), 1000); 
    }

    printContent = () => {
      console.log('print content'); 
    }

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.isFocused)
        return(
            <div>
                <input onFocus={this.handleFocus} onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
                {
                    this.state.isFocused ? 
                        <div key='1' onClick={this.printContent}>content1</div> : 
                        null
                }
            </div>
        ); 
    }
}
```